# How do I change/edit kernel name (the one in uname -r)?

Tags: raspbian, kernel

I tried to change kernel version name of Raspbian using the steps in http://goterminal.blogspot.com/2012/02/make-kernel-name-same-as-your-name_07.html meant for Ubuntu.

For example I want to change the kernel version name from `4.4.30-7+` to `4.4.30-7+-Afif-Custom`

The steps are stated like this:

> 1. sudo apt-get install kernel-wedge kernel-package libncurses5-dev
> 2. sudo apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)
> 3. mkdir ~/src
> 4. cd ~/src
> 5. sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
> 6. cd linux-2.6.38 (__I presume a different directory name will appear there__)
> 7. make menuconfig
> 8. export CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=3
>
>    - Concurrency_level  = 2 ( Number of processor cores)  +  1
> 9. make-kpkg clean
> 10. time fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-tweak kernel-image kernel-headers
> 11. cd ~/src
> 12. sudo dpkg -i linux-image-2.6.38.2-tweak_2.6.38.2-tweak-10.00.Custom_i386.deb
> 13. sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-2.6.38.2-tweak_2.6.38.2-tweak-10.00.Custom_i386.deb
> 14. sudo reboot (or) sudo init 6
> 15. uname -r

I'm stumped for days at step 2. The `linux-image-$(uname -r)` part doesn't work for me. I'm currently using Raspbian kernel version `4.4.30-v7+`. Even when I use `4.4.27-7+` the `linux-image-$(uname -r)` part won't work too... It says the version does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, you have to rebuild the kernel in order to change the name it uses.  However, it is not worthwhile doing just for that purpose, honestly.  These instructions aren't really any good either.  Basically you would go about compiling the kernel normally (there are lots of pi-specific instructions around for that), and when you run `make menuconfig` there's an option (*General setup -> Local version*) in there to append a suffix (`-v7+` is an example of that).  Changing the version string completely to something unrelated is going to be harder and probably a bad idea.

Comment: It's only for educational purpose. Just for the sake of knowing how to do that. :)

Comment: Ugh how dumb of me to miss this link http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation#1._On_the_Raspberry_Pi :D

I'll immediately try it and post if something happened (as it was stated as quite outdated)